# are dist folders always available in node modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

i am building a tool of my own to trans compile and pack the related js files (that are written in ES6) into a bundle. so far it goes as expected with local files, but when i come to public modules, for example, react and redux etc, it's different. and i am wondering how to include these modules into the bundle? i found that there are always dist folders in most of the public modules with distributed versions residing in. so, are the dist folders always available in any module directory?

Comment: No, it will depend on the specific third party library.

Comment: No, `@angular` and `rxjs` to name a few, does not have `dist` folder.

Comment: then how to include, say, the distributed version of any module ?

Comment: or how does webpack handler these problems ?

Answer (score 5):

Webpack uses the same module resolution as [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). `node_modules` have a `package.json` which has a `main` field, that determines which file is being imported when you import the module in your code. Additionally webpack looks for the `browser` or `module` fields in `package.json` and prefers them over `main`, if they are present. This makes it easy to publish a build that is different from the regular Node.js build (for instance to use ES modules (`import`/`export`), which are not supported by yet Node.js but by bundlers like webpack). This behaviour can be configured with the option [resolve.mainFields](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields). For an example have a look at the [`package.json` of Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/a56339d0db94e5d5b85a2bfe02ec49ac51af0073/package.json#L5-L8).

None of these fields are mandatory, but at least `main` is supposed to be present, so you can simply import a module with:

```
import module from 'module';
```

Or with `require`:

```
const module = require('module');
```

Webpack automatically includes the modules you import into the bundle.

---

The `dist`  directory is not any special, but it's very common to have a `dist` directory that contains an UMD build. Especially as [Unpkg](https://unpkg.com/) allows you to import a node module without having to publish it manually to a CDN, it uses the `dist` or `umd` by default (as described at the bottom of the homepage).